# android threads unclear

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have this code:

```
package org.example.Threading;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ThreadingActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private doinback background = new doinback();
    Handler handle= new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Log.e("INSIDE HANDLER", "About to stop the thread.");
        background.stopThread();
        }};
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        Log.e("ONCREATE", "BEFORE Thread");
        background.start();
        Log.e("ONCREATE", "AFTER Thread started");

        View button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    class doinback extends Thread{
        private volatile boolean isRunning = false;
        public void run() {
            while(isRunning){
                Log.e("INSIDE THREAD", "about to sleep");
                handle.sendMessage(handle.obtainMessage());
            }

        }
        public void stopThread()
        {
            isRunning = false;
        }
        public void startThread(){
            Log.e("INSIDE StartThread","MAKING isRunning True");
            isRunning = true;
        }
        }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        background.startThread();
        Log.e("INSIDE ONCLICK", "made isRunning true, about to leave");

    }
}
```

I am trying to understand why it does not go back to the thread and if there is something I am doing wrong and if so what is the best way to go back and forth from a thread, for instance with the stopThread() function I change the value of the while variable to stop the thread from running. When I run the code and press the button it does not start the thread. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `background.start()` is called, `isRunning` is still false, so the thread is started(but didn't enter the while loop) and stopped immediately.

To ensure the thread to enter the while loop when `startThread` is called, you can put the following code in the `startThread()` method:

```
public void startThread(){
    isRunning = true;
    start();
}
```

And you don't call `background.start()` in `onCreate()`, just remove that line.

**EDIT**

If you want to keep a single thread alive, so you can "start" it and "stop" it as many times as you like, you can use the following code:

```
public void run () {
    while (isRunning) {
        if(!isWorking) {
            try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch (InterruptedException ex) { }
            continue;
        }
        //.. do your work here.
    }
}
```

You control the running state of the thread with `isRunning`, and the working state with `isWorking`.

Comment: The reason I do not want to put the start in the startThread is because I might need to call that thread multiple times and I will get a start already started exeception. the function startThread is to just change the variable so the thread will start again...or that is what I want to achieve. Is there any better way to do it? Pretty much like a restart type of action....

Comment: My main concern is, why isn't my code doing what it is meant to do? Like when you run this code it does not do what it is suppose to do, why? Isn't it suppose to build a UI with a button and when I click that button it is going to change the variable to true which should make the thread run...but the thread does not run, why?

Comment: The first paragraph(2 lines) of my answer has already explained the reason. Have you read my answer, man?

Comment: OK, in case you still don't get my answer, I will explain a little bit more. *Isn't it suppose to build a UI with a button and when I click that button it is going to change the variable to true which should make the thread run* - This is wrong! before you click that button, the thread **already ran though its lifecycle**, it was started in `onCreate` and it immediately tested the `isRunning` flag, but it was **false**, so the thread died, all this happened before you click, or even see that button. The thread **won't** wait there for you to turn `isRunning` to `true`.